# how to add a record in a sub-level transaction using procedure in genexus without Business Componet

Tags: genexus

I'm just learning more about genexus and wanted to know if there was a way to do this.

As the title says, i just want to know how to add a sublevel Transaccion without using Business component, I have readed the majority of "new", "for each", "blocking" and other stuff on genexus wiki, but to no luck.

For example, let's say we have this transaccion:

```
Person
{
 PersonId
 PersonName

 City
 {
  CityId
  CityName
 }
}
```

I have a record with a Person, and want to add his City, how would i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you hold the Person Id in `&PersonId`, then you would issue:

```
new
  PersonId = &PersonId
  CityId = ...
  CityName = ...
when duplicate   // This is optional
  ...  // do something if there already exists a tuple PersonId/CityId with those values
endnew
```

In this sample, I am assuming you have a table *Person* with key `PersonId` and a table *PersonCity* with key `PersonId, CityId`

Don't forget to `commit` the transaction explicitly or implicitly (by having the procedure property *Commit on Exit* set to `yes`).

Answer (score 0):

For a defensive approach that person exists, you can surround the "new" with a for each on person like this:

```
for each Person
  where PersonId = &PersonId

  new
    Defined by PersonId
    CityId = ...
    CityName = ...
  when duplicate   // This is optional
    ...  // do something if there already exists a tuple PersonId/CityId with those values
  endnew
endfor
```